# NODEJS Express application generator for API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

Currently the Express JS **Express application generator** supports to generate initial App or we call it a **Boilerplate** using the `npx express-generator` or `express myapp` commands based on the Express version and the structure of the app is as below,

```
   app/public/
   app/public/javascripts/
   app/public/images/
   app/public/stylesheets/
   app/public/stylesheets/style.css
   app/routes/
   app/routes/index.js
   app/routes/users.js
   app/views/
   app/views/error.jade
   app/views/index.jade
   app/views/layout.jade
   app/app.js
   app/package.json
   app/bin/
   app/bin/www
```

Lets say I need to create only a API so in that case I do not need the followings in the generated app;

```
   app/public/javascripts/
   app/public/images/
   app/public/stylesheets/
   app/public/stylesheets/style.css
   ...
   app/views/
   app/views/error.jade
   app/views/index.jade
   app/views/layout.jade
```

in such cases is there a **WAY** or **COMMAND** to generate the App only specified to API APP including packages like `body-parser` and without unwanted files and folders that I have mentioned above.

TIA.

Comment: No, express-generator generates a complete application including views/styles. You need to manually remove the files. You would only need to do this once ever for an application, what issue are you specifically running into?

Comment: If you really need to achieve this then you can go with shell script. It will help you much at certain level.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky There is no specific issues I am running into but wanted to know if there is standard way of achieving this.

Answer (score 5):

My answer is too late, but this could be an interesting option to use.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator-api

It creates a lightweight express app with all you need to start developing an API using expressjs.

Comment: It's not too late. This is a good concern indeed.

Answer (score 1):

`express-generator` does not have such an option. There is some [movement](https://github.com/expressjs/generator/pull/198) towards this.

The "standard" way to bootstrap a new Express application that is optimized for modern Node environments and applications is to roll your own bootstrap/starter project and reuse this.

There are some tools like [Cookiecutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter) out there that claim to help you with this task.

I personally have an `my-express-starter` repo which does not include any view engines etc, but middleware for Apis.

Comment: Informative and hope that the mentioned movement will end up ASAP.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your `my-express-starter` repo? @madflow

Comment: @YardenShoham I have used this on in the past: https://gitlab.com/madflow/express-starter . There many others...